# How can I bend a rectangle in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

let's imagine I have a SKSprite node. for reference, I will give an example:

```
let rect = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 300))
rect.position.x = self.frame.midX
rect.position.y = self.frame.midY
self.addChild(rect)
```

so you can imagine it is a thin tall blue rectangle. How would I go about animating the node to bend the middle part from left to right and repeat infinitely?I will provide a image to give a more clear understanding:

start:
[image]

next frame:
[image]

next frame:
[image]

Sorry if the quality of the images is bad. The only thing is that I want it to animate, Otherwise I could have used static images.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe you should use **warpGeometry**

[image]

I don't know if your runforever create a bad performance.

check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skwarpgeometrygrid)

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will create performance issues because I will have many of them running at the same time, and repeating forever, but it is still better than any other solution I have got till now.

Comment: @Rishi if you have many of them, is better to use gameplaykit, add this as component

Comment: But all I really am trying to do, is simulate the movement of waves. So I guess I will just have to create at least 10 images, and use images for the animation. If I use images, It should lag as much, I hope.

Comment: I'dont think that images can lag, but you must preserve the physics body?

Comment: no, I won't be using a physics body, if I use the images

Comment: A good way to avoid performance issues is to turn them into SKTextures when done and apply the warped texture to a new sprite