# SpriteKit - How to make a perspective scrolling background

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I know how to make a endless scrolling background in SpriteKit, but I don't know how to make a perspective background.

Please look at the image below, the left is the origin resource, the right is what I want, and it should scrolling from top to bottom.

[image]

---

As @Simone Pistecchia and @Knight0fDragon said, I tried use `SKWarpGeometryGrid`

```
let src = [
    float2(0, 0), float2(0.33, 0), float2(0.67, 0), float2(1, 0),
    float2(0, 1), float2(0.33, 1), float2(0.67, 1), float2(1, 1)
]

let dst = [
    float2(0, 0), float2(0.33, 0), float2(0.67, 0), float2(1, 0),
    float2(0.33, 1), float2(0.33, 1), float2(0.67, 1), float2(0.67, 1)
]

let back = childNode(withName: "bgNode") as! SKSpriteNode
back.warpGeometry = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 3, rows: 1, sourcePositions: src, destinationPositions: dst)
```

The code result is the middle image below, the left is origin resource, the right is what I want.

[The result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS7x3.jpg)

Comment: Are you going to have any 3D objects? If so, consider using `SceneKit`.

Comment: chek my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442914/how-can-i-bend-a-rectangle-in-sprite-kit/45443365#45443365

Comment: emm.. just the background is perspective, other objects is 2D

Comment: transform the endless background with `SKWarpGeometryGrid` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skwarpgeometrygrid

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have tried `SKWarpGeometryGrid`, the rectangle can transform to trapezoid, but it didn't be perspective... @SimonePistecchia

Comment: Why not, post the image

Comment: @SimonePistecchia I posted the code and the result in the description

Comment: I never used SKWarp, but I think you're in the right way. Just add more rows and you have what you want

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have try,but it can't...

Comment: You do what simone says and make it longer, then combine with an skcropnode to clip at the cutoff point

Comment: @Knight0fDragon sorry, I don't know what mean "make it longer", may you post some code?

Comment: Nope, when you warp it, do not just squeeze the tip, also stretch it back.  I would stretch it back and make it a triangle actually, then crop where you need